# Data synchronization between on premise SQL Server database and SQL Azure database by using CDC and SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, cdc

How can we achieve data synchronization between on premise SQL Server database and SQL Azure database by using change data capture and SQL Server Integration Services?

Comment: Suggest you go away, think about it, do some research, think about it some more, come up with a solution and then ask a question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use DATA SYNC (CTP2) to do the same.

Comment: yes that's true. Alternatively, you can create your own custom solution for now. Here's an article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/08/31/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization-using-sync-framework-2-1.aspx